# Sockets.io issue: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, webrtc

I am currently building a nodejs webrtc video conference, hosted on azure. The program works perfectly fine locally, but when hosted there seems to be an issue with websockets. The client side error is below:

```
WebSocket connection to '<URL>' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

```
index.js:83 WebSocket connection to 'wss://etuition.azurewebsites.net:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

I have seen other stack overflow posts claiming that this is due to SSL, but site is currently running on  HTTPS so this should not be a problem for me. Is it possible that the ws server is insecure even though my http server is secure?

Any other advice on what could be the problem will be greatly appreciated.
Below I have included my server.js code.
Please ask if any more information is needed:

```js
/**
 * Server module.
 *
 *
 */

'use strict';

var environment = process.env.RTC_ENV || 'local';
var debug = require('debug')('expressapp:server');

var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');
var logger = require('./logger').logger(environment);


var serverPort = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8080');
//var serverPort = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8080');


function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);
  
    if (isNaN(port)) {
      // named pipe
      return val;
    }
  
    if (port >= 0) {
      // port number
      return port;
    }
  
    return false;
  }
  
//var serverPort = process.env.RTC_PORT || 31000
var serverIpAddress = process.env.RTC_IP || 'localhost'
var  socketIoServer = 'etuition.azurewebsites.net' + ':' + serverPort;

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SETUP SERVER
////////////////////////////////////////////////
var app = express();

app.set('port', serverPort);


function redirectSec(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] == 'http') {
        var redirect = 'https://' + req.headers.host + req.path;
        console.log('Redirect to:' + redirect);
        res.redirect(redirect);
    } else {
        return next();
    }
}

app.use(redirectSec);

require('./router')(app, socketIoServer, environment);

// Static content (css, js, .png, etc) is placed in /public
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(cors());

// Location of our views
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// Use ejs as our rendering engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Tell Server that we are actually rendering HTML files through EJS.
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(serverPort);
server.on('listening', onListening);


function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
      ? 'pipe ' + addr
      : 'port ' + addr.port;
    debug('Listening on ' + bind);
    logger.info("Socket IO Address:" + socketIoServer);
    logger.info("Server IP Address:" + serverIpAddress);
    logger.info('Server running on port ' + serverPort);
  } 

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { log: false, origins: '*:*' });

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// EVENT HANDLERS
////////////////////////////////////////////////


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    function log() {
        var array = [">>> Message from server: "];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            array.push(arguments[i]);
        }
        socket.emit('log', array);
    }

    socket.on('message', function (message) {
        log('Got message: ', message);
        logger.info("message: ", message);
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('message', message);
    });

    socket.on('create or join', function (message) {
        var room = message.room;
        socket.room = room;
        var participantID = message.from;
        configNameSpaceChannel(participantID);

        io.of('/').in(room).clients(function (error, clients) {
            var numClients = clients.length;

            log('Room ' + room + ' has ' + numClients + ' client(s)');
            log('Request to create or join room', room);

            if (numClients == 0) {
                logger.info(participantID + " joined first. Creates room " + room);
                socket.join(room);
                socket.emit('created', room);
            } else {
                logger.info(participantID + " joins room " + room);
                io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
                socket.join(room);
                socket.emit('joined', room);
            }
        })
    });

    // Setup a communication channel (namespace) to communicate with a given participant (participantID)
    function configNameSpaceChannel(room) {
        var nsp = '/' + room;
        var socketNamespace = io.of(nsp);

        logger.info('ConfigNameSpaceChannel:' + nsp);

        socketNamespace.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.on('message', function (message) {
                // Send message to everyone BUT sender
                socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
            });

        });

        return socketNamespace;
    }

});
```

Comment: Your wss url points to port 8080? You've specifically started the SSL server at 8080 (its typically run at 443)? Also, are you using nginx for reverse proxy/SSL termination? If so you'd need extra setup to make nginx forward the WS connections.

Comment: Try to use `wss://etuition.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket` or `wss://etuition.azurewebsites.net:443/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket`.

Comment: If by hosted in Azure, you mean AKS (is it?), I might have the solution.

Comment: @C.Derx what was this solution you had for AKS? Having similar issues with GKE (google cloud kubernetes) and I'm thinking this is an issue with ingress potentially

Comment: @mpetts for K8s env, the issue rooted from multi-node deployment. (https://socket.io/docs/v2/using-multiple-nodes/index.html). I worked around it (no final solution) by reducing replica to 1. Live: (`k -n {you-ns} scale deploy {app-name} --replicas=1`) or update your yaml.